# Load drop down menu in HTML from another file

Tags: html, file, load, drop-down-menu

Is there anyway to load the drop down menu of an html from another file(A text file) ?

I tried this and I guess it is not working.

```
<form>
<select name  = "Name">
<!--#include virtual="options.txt" -->
</select>
</form>
```

and inside options.txt

```
<option value = "42a">42A</option>
<option value = "42b">42B</option>
<option value = "42c">42C</option>
<option value = "42d">42D</option>
<option value = "42e">42E</option>
<option value = "43a">43A</option>
```

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to use server-side includes, server-side scripts (php, and so on) or client-side scripts (javascript/jQuery, etc.). Which would you be willing to accept or work with?

Comment: Which server side code are you working with?

Comment: I just know Perl..or thats what I think.Would like to stick to it. Is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by using html templates and Perl-CGI. The include of template works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Load on the server in java / jsp

```
<%@ include file="drop_down.jspf" %>
// Or 
<jsp:include page="<%=variable_containing_relative_path_to_drop_down.jspf%>" />
```

Load by the browser in javascript / jQuery

```
$("#my_container").load("http://mon_site.com/fragment/drop_down.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a [server side include.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

```
<!--#include virtual="../header.txt" -->
```

Comment: In order for a server-side include to work, you first must be using the correct path (#virtual path is relative to the root folder). Secondly, you must be using either an Apache, Lighttbd, or IIS server.